# richface4: Add specific a4j:status to rich:autocomplete

Tags: richfaces

A global status is there for general ajax request to trigger, and I want another different status for the autocomplete.

but
if a4j:status with no name, it will be triggered by other ajax request.
if a4j:status with name, it can't be mapped with rich:autocomplete

Anyone has experience with this?

---

it'd found as an open issue of richfaces https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-10966
any workaround here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<a4j:ajax>` to point to the status.

Edit:

autocomplete has some issues with attached `<a4j:ajax>`. This works:

```
<a4j:status id="global />
<a4j:status name="status" />

<rich:autocomplete onkeyup="update();" … >
<a4j:jsFunction name="update">
    <a4j:ajax event="begin" status="status"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

you cannot prevent the global status from picking up on the autocomplete, the only thing you can do is to hide it - `$('#form\\:global').hide()`. But I don't think there's a reliable way to hide it before it triggers.

Comment: thank you for reply, but rich:autocomplete still triggers other global a4j:status.   like the "keyup" event did not triggered.  Did you give it a try?

Comment: I thought you need to bind a status to the autocomplete component, do you need both global and a named status?

Comment: A global *status* is there for general ajax request to trigger, and I want another different *status* for the *autocomplete*. I updated the question description. can you please help?

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it's kind of big workaround, I prefer using the original autocompleteMethod="xxx" as suggest method